# Acrobat fullscreen mode not working as intended on Microsoft Surface

Tags: windows-8, adobe-acrobat, windows-tabletpc

I have a .pdf file that uses lots of javascript-driven buttons, and which **must** be displayed on a Microsoft Surface in fullscreen mode.

Everything works exactly as intended, with one exception:

If a user accidentally uses the touch screen to click anywhere outside of the physical borders of a javascript button, then the Surface seems to interpret this as the user attempting to exit full screen mode-- so accidentally clicking *just* outside the border of a button has the effect of exiting full screen mode and displaying the .pdf document in "restore" view instead.

This only happens when the user is using the touchscreen. Mouse clicks that occur outside of the physical borders of the buttons do not produce the same behavior.

I need to disable this behavior, so that a touchscreen click outside of any buttons simply has no effect whatsoever.

Can anyone venture a guess as to why this is happening, or how to prevent it?

(Resizing the buttons to make them larger/easier to press is not an option.)

EDIT 1 (Including some Meta-): I've actually just discovered [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/985510/viewing-pdf-in-kiosk-mode?rq=1) which appears to ask the exact same question, albeit in terms that would not have occurred to me the look for in a search of prior SU posts. I would assume that this current post is effectively a duplicate, and in all likelihood ought to be deleted. However, since I don't have sufficient rights on this forum to cost a comment, I'll leave it to others to pull the trigger on deleting this post, since I'm now adding a comment here that I cannot add in the linked thread.

Comment: In the linked thread above, user @MaxWyss suggests that unchecking the "Escape quites FullScreen" option from the Acrobat preferences menu might address the issue. I have tested that, and it does not work in my case. The "tap outside of button -> exit fullscreen" behavior seems to result from a particular setting on the Surface Pro itself, although not one that I've been able to find and change so far

Comment: Update: A little more info...clicking or double-clicking or double-clicking within the .pdf document, but outside of any buttons using an attached mouse will not exit full screen mode. Single-clicking using the touchpad on the attached Surface Pro keyboard will not exit full screen mode, but double-cliking using the keyboard touchpad will. Single-clicking or tapping using the touchscreen will exit full screen mode. .......... Thre different pieces of hardware, three different results from the same set of actions (single- / double - clicking).

Comment: It seems like there really *ought* to be some way of accessing and editing the settings or preferences that govern the different behavior that the same actions have on these different items of hardware...can anyone confirm that though?

Comment: Which Acrobat/Reader version are you using? Or are you using another PDF viewer?

Comment: My apologies, I should have included that info in the OP. I'm running Acrobat Standard DC on the Surface where I'm getting the troublesome behavior, although the document itself was created using Acrobat XI on another machine.

Comment: Thanks; I can't remember hearing about such issues. Maybe someone else can help, or at least attempt to reproduce the problem.